# Coffescript not compiling valid source

Tags: coffeescript

I'm calling this function and get error in this place: `data: { key: node.parent.data.key }` saing "Unexpected {". Is there something wrong. because I can't find the error.

```
 $("#discipline-list", @el).dynatree({
        fx: { height: "toggle", 
        duration: 100 },
        initAjax: {
          url: "/disciplines",
          data: { mode: "funnyMode" }
        },
        onLazyRead: (node) ->
            console.log(node);
            node.appendAjax({url: "/disciplines_details",
                data: { key: node.parent.data.key }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Coffee script is not appreciating having the anonymous object properties on the same line. Adding a single newline fixes this...

```
 $("#discipline-list", @el).dynatree({
        fx: { height: "toggle", 
        duration: 100 },
        initAjax: {
          url: "/disciplines",
          data: { mode: "funnyMode" }
        },
        onLazyRead: (node) ->
            console.log(node);
            node.appendAjax({
                url: "/disciplines_details",
                data: { key: node.parent.data.key }
            });
        });
```

---

EDIT: How to convert js to coffee script...

go to http://js2coffee.org/ and paste the js (corrected from your version)

```
$("#discipline-list", this.el).dynatree({
    fx: { height: "toggle", 
    duration: 100 },
    initAjax: {
        url: "/disciplines",
        data: { mode: "funnyMode" }
    },
    onLazyRead: function(node){
        console.log(node);
        node.appendAjax({ url: "/disciplines_details",
            data: { key: node.parent.data.key }
        });
    }
});
```

You will end up with well formed coffee script...

```
$("#discipline-list", @el).dynatree
  fx:
    height: "toggle"
    duration: 100

  initAjax:
    url: "/disciplines"
    data:
      mode: "funnyMode"

  onLazyRead: (node) ->
    console.log node
    node.appendAjax
      url: "/disciplines_details"
      data:
        key: node.parent.data.key
```

Comment: Also, as shown by @jkbr, it can have an awful lot of syntax removed to make it more readable in coffee-script

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is wrong, but the more canonical way to write it would be

```
node.appendAjax
  url: "/disciplines_details"
  data: 
    key: node.parent.data.key
```

With compile errors like that, always first go to [Try Coffeescript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) and see how it gets parsed. That makes it very easy and quick to fix in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

The object properties on the same line are confusing the parser:

```
node.appendAjax({url: "/disciplines_details",
```

Just move `url` to the next line and it should work:

```
node.appendAjax({
    url: "/disciplines_details",
```

That said, you're still writing javascript.

Whitespace is significant in coffeescript (i.e. you can't minify it). Correct indentation is essential, and this code is all wrong. Fix indentation, get rid of commas and semi-colons:

```
$("#discipline-list", @el).dynatree({
    fx: {
        height: "toggle"
        duration: 100
    }
    initAjax: {
        url: "/disciplines",
        data: { mode: "funnyMode" }
    }
    onLazyRead: (node) ->
        console.log(node)
        node.appendAjax({
            url: "/disciplines_details"
            data: { key: node.parent.data.key }
        })
})
```

Then proceed to get rid of brackets and parenthesis as in @Billy's last sample. If you're not comfortable you should try sticking to plain javascript for some time.